# I cannot find rtl support for ng-bootstrap (for right to left language)

Tags: right-to-left, ng-bootstrap

Is there a rtl support for ng-bootstrap (for arabic, hebrew etc')?
I am writing a project in right to left language in angular 4 and would like to use ng-bootstrap.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this patch for full RTL compatibility for both Bootstrap 3.3.7 and 4.0.0-alpha.6
https://github.com/parsmizban/RTL-Bootstrap
If you have any pre designed theme, You can use this path to make your template RTL very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the direction for some components like ngb-pagination

```
direction: ltr;
```

It makes sense to set the direction as LTR everywhere for such commun displays (e.g., numbers based)